# How does RxSwift work if you click a UIButton?

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I've just started learning `RxSwift`. I've added a `UIButton` with an observable in and a suscribe method that should trigger everytime data changes, but I don't get it to work. What am I missing?

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    publishableSubject.onNext("GURKA")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let bag = DisposeBag()
    _ = publishableSubject.subscribe(onNext: {
        print($0)
    }).disposed(by: bag)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dispose bag is local so it de-inits when viewDidLoad exits and that will dispose the observable chain you setup. For what you describe, just moving the dispose bag to the class level should fix it.

```
let publishableSubject = PublishSubject<String>()
let bag = DisposeBag()

@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    publishableSubject.onNext("GURKA")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    publishableSubject
        .subscribe(onNext: {
            print($0)
        })
        .disposed(by: bag)
}
```

You might want to consider importing the `RxCocoa` library as well. It sets up the action for you so you can write less code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myButton.rx.tap
        .map { "GURKA" }
        .subscribe(onNext: {
            print($0)
        })
        .disposed(by: bag)
}
```

Comment: Nice, it worked perfectly! Thanks alot for you assistance @Daniel T. and thanks for the additional info. Will check it out :D